# Decoding capital letters from query string

Tags: c#, urlencode

The QueryString contains `foo=Þórþ Örnö Ægirssonð`

When I decode it as `UTF8` it works for `ð, ö, æ` but not for the upper case version `Ð, Ö, Þ`

```
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Request.QueryString["foo"]);
            var value = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Here is how this string looks before decoding `ÃÃ³rÃ¾ ÃrnÃ¶ ÃgirssonÃ°`

And here is how it looks after decoding to UTF8 `�?órþ �?rnö �?girssonð`

Am I missing something? I have tried decoding as UTF7 and any set that works for Icelandic that I found in the [Encoding Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are (probably) using two different encodings: `Default` for producing the byte array and `UTF8` for rebuilding the string. Chances are that on your PC `Default` differs from `UTF8`, and this is messing things up.

You must be careful when using `Encoding.Default`. Here is how it works (directly quoted from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx)):

> Different computers can use different encodings as the default, and
>   the default encoding can even change on a single computer. Therefore,
>   data streamed from one computer to another or even retrieved at
>   different times on the same computer might be translated incorrectly.
>   In addition, the encoding returned by the Default property uses
>   best-fit fallback to map unsupported characters to characters
>   supported by the code page. For these two reasons, using the default
>   encoding is generally not recommended. To ensure that encoded bytes
>   are decoded properly, you should use a Unicode encoding, such as
>   UTF8Encoding or UnicodeEncoding, with a preamble. Another option is to
>   use a higher-level protocol to ensure that the same format is used for
>   encoding and decoding.

The `UTF8` encoding should be what you are looking for in this case, but you have to apply it coherently:

```
Byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Request.QueryString["foo"]);
String value = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Look at [this demo](http://rextester.com/CJTUB53944), it works fine for me.